# Issue of interpreting 64-bit to 32-bit integer in SIMD register

Tags: casting, type-conversion, simd, endianness, intrinsics

I am quite confused of the above interpretion issue. I set a 256-bit vector register with 4 * 64-bit integer value `2^32` using intrinsics like this:

```
    __m256i vec_mask = _mm256_set1_epi64x(1 << 32);
```

then I would like to interpret it as 8 * 32-bit integers:

```
    __m256i * tmp_mask = new __m256i;
    _mm256_storeu_si256(tmp_mask, vec_mask); // store
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        printf("%d ", ((int *)(tmp_mask))[i]);
    delete tmp_mask;
```

As for each 64-bit value `2^32`, I think it is like this in SIMD register:

`00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`

`255 (MSB) ----------------------------------------------------- 0 (LSB)`

So each 64-bit value `2^32` is interpreted as `<1, 0>` in 2 * 32-bit format. The final output is expected to be `<0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1>` from low to high, but the output is quite weird: `<0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0>`.

Any idea where I made a mistake? Thanks.

Comment: The mistake is writing `1 << 32` in the first place

Comment: @harold Sorry I did not quite get your point. You mean first keeping `1 << 32` in a variable `a` then using `_mm256_set1_epi64x(a)` ?

Comment: To expand on the comment by @harold, remember that `1` is an `int` which first of all is signed, and second of all is usually only 32 bits on all known platforms. When you do `1 << 32` you overflow this signed 32-bit integer which leads to *undefined behavior*. You need to use an unsigned type, and one that is larger than 32 bits. Like `unsigned long long` which you get with the `ull` suffix, as in `1ull << 32`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Quite clear. I was not aware of that. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code outputs `0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1` as you expect...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

int main() {
     __m256i vec_mask = _mm256_set1_epi64x(UINT64_C(1) << 32);
    uint32_t tmp_mask[8];
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i *)tmp_mask, vec_mask); // store
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        printf("%d ", tmp_mask[i]);
}
```